# Why does Unity automatically outline my images?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, png

my Unity is automatically outlining my images. Do you know why and how I can turn it off? Here is how it should look like (looks like in windows fotos):
[image]

And here how it looks like in Unity. Any tips on how to remove this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried Using Raw Image and normal Image but none worked.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Texture Import Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html) lets you set the texture details. In your case, I’d suggest starting with a Clamp for Wrap Mode, and Point for Filter Mode.

Comment: It worked, thanks!! Any explanation on why you have to do that/what they do :)?

Comment: @RezarakSL the Unity docs give you a start, but they’re not really in depth on what the different settings do. But, briefly, when you’ve got biliniear filtering, it’s trying to smooth the pixels with the neighbouring ones. When you’ve got a repeating texture, the far right hand side gets “blurred” with the far left hand side. In your case, that’s the red border on the left hand side. Trust me, it makes sense once it clicks. 